# Get item out of array in Swift

Tags: json, swift

I'm very new to Swift and have spent several hours just trying to pull the `photo_url` key out of a JSON response.

I'm using this for the reading the JSON:

```
let jsonDictionary = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data, options: .mutableContainers)
```

Then:

```
                if let eventsDictionary = jsonDictionary {
                    let upcomingEvents = UpcomingEvents(eventsDictionary: eventsDictionary)
                    completion(upcomingEvents)
                } else {
                    completion(nil)
                }
```

Here is my (failed) attempt to pull out the key:

```
init(eventsDictionary: [String : Any]) {
    //photoUrl = eventsDictionary[EventKeys.photoUrl] as? String
    let groups: NSArray = eventsDictionary["groups"] as! NSArray
    let url: String = groups[0]
   print("THIS IS YOUR RETURNED PHOTO URL--\(url)--END OF RETURNED PHOTO URL")
}
```

[image]

I changed "[String: Any]" to [String: AnyObject] and now i get this... 
[image]

Comment: What does your JSON response look like? What error do you get?

Comment: Why use `NSArray`? There's no good reason for that. Cast the array to a Swift array type instead (probably `[String]` since that's what the array seems to contain). Also, use `as?` rather than `as!`, and handle the case where you get `nil`.

Comment: I added a screenshot of the response

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are problems casting Any to NSArray. Just make your Init method taking [String:AnyObject]. But, better use Array instead of NSArray here

Comment: I'made the changes you suggested but im still not able to pull out the last photo_url field

Comment: @Verty00 it’s because of .mutableContainer option. Read more about serializing options. Here you don’t need them

Answer (score 0):

Try to get url use following code.

```
let firstObj  = groups[0] as! [String: String] // use if let to unwrap is better
let url = firstObj["photo_url"]
```

Comment: Forgot to say the first posted answer's suggestion is very good for your programming.

Answer (score 0):

To get "photo_url" from the json file in your photo,

it looks like this:

```
init(eventsDictionary: [String : Any]) {
   if let groups = eventsDictionary["groups"] as? [NSDictionary]{
        /*
        // Get All URL
        var urls : [String] = []
        for group in groups{
            if let url = group.value(forKey: "photo_url"){
                urls.append(url)
            }
        }
        */

        // Groups[0] url
        let url: String = groups[0].value(forKey: "photo_url") as! String
        print("THIS IS YOUR RETURNED PHOTO URL--\(url)--END OF RETURNED PHOTO URL")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to read json as `[String: Any].

```
 if let eventsDictionary = json as? [String: Any] {
     let upcomingEvents = UpcomingEvents(eventsDictionary: eventsDictionary)
     completion(upcomingEvents)               
 }
```

Then, init your `UpcomingEvents` model like this

```
init(eventsDictionary: [String : Any]) {
    let groups: NSArray = eventsDictionary["groups"] as! NSArray
    let group1 = groups[0] as! NSDictionary
    let photoURL = group1["photo_url"] as! String
    print(photoURL)
}
```